# How can I dump a view to a table so it doesn't have to recalculate

Tags: oracle, caching, sql-view

I have a very complicated view that's a holdover from a legacy part of the code. We're not interested in changing that view even though it has some minor bugs in it because it's just way too messy. But we don't exactly have the hours available to re-write it. So we need to speed up its performance without modifying it.

What I was going to do was have a batch job that has a table with identical columns and once in a while it clears the data in that table and inserts into that table each row from the view. So even though it takes 5 minutes to calculate the entire view, we'd only have to do it once a day, or if they REALLY want the report to be accurate (and wait for it to recalculate) the client can re-trigger the batch job.

There's a couple different ways I can think to do it, but they seem naive and rather hackish. Is there a 'standard' way to accomplish this task that I'm just not finding?

Comment: What you are describing already exists in Oracle, it is called a Materialized View: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm#i34980

Comment: Thanks for that link, Tony. I'm investigating it now, but I'm not finding switches that would allow it to access stale data. I would need the be able to access this data while it's in a stale state, and only rebuild the materialized view every few hours.

Comment: @corsiKa By default, a materialized view has stale data.  Enabling incremental or fast-refresh can be very difficult, you're in luck if you don't want that feature.  Materialized views can be both scheduled to rebuild and rebuilt ad hoc.